# how to write the gulp file when compiling jade files and wanting to keep the relative paths correct?

Tags: compilation, gulp, pug, relative-path

what I want is to compile the **update.jade** (under **src** dir) to be update.html (under **dist** dir). **style.css** under src and dist directories are the same. When I compiled the file, I just found the link to the *.css file was not changed, so that the page cannot be right. It should be "css/style.css" instead of "../../css/style.css"

> my dir structure is as follows

```
├──src
   ├──css
      ├──style.css
   ├──update.jade
   ├──templates
      ├──layout.jade
      ├──incl
         ├──head.jade
├──dist
   ├──css
      ├──style.css
   ├──upate.html
```

> And followings are relative jade files

**layout.jade**

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  include incl/head.jade
  body
```

**head.jade**

```
head
  meta(charset='utf-8')/
  title Update
  link(href='../../css/style.css', rel='stylesheet')/
```

**update.jade**

```
extends templates/layout.jade
block content
  div#main
```

However, the generated update.html file still kept the old reference URL path to style.css file, and this made me at loss.

**generated update.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Update</title>
    <link href="../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I guess the problem is at the compiling stage, but I tried a lot with gulp and the parameters. I just don't know how to set the smart para to let the relative URLs be correct.

> the gulp file as follows

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    jade = require('gulp-jade'),
    path = require('path');

gulp.task('jade', function() {
    gulp.src('src/**/*.jade')
        .pipe(jade({
            pretty: true,
            filename: 'layout.jade',
            basedir: path.resolve()
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
```